# What are the steps for migrating from Play! 1.1 to 2.0?

Tags: playframework, upgrade

Is there any documentation on how to migrate from Play! 1.1 to Play! 2.0? I understand that I would need to rewrite the templates, but what additional steps would I need to perform to be up to date?

The app is written in Java with some jQuery with AJAX. I'm not using any NHibernate in it.

On a similar note, is the effort actually worth it? Or should I upgrade to 1.2 and not worry about 2.0?

Comment: Cześć Miachał, there is no bigger sense to trying evaluate your 1.x Play code to version 2.0, there are to many differences. If you need to upgrade to 2.0 you should just rewrite your application. In other case, there is big chance, that 1.x branch will be maintained (and what's best also improved) for some time. Conclusion, keep your existing project at branch 1.x and start new ones with Play 2.0

Comment: Miało być Michał :] excuse me

Comment: I suggest waiting for play 2.1 or 2.2 as there still is a lot missing compared to 1.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play 2 is not play1.2.5+, which means you don't get all the features you get in play1.2.4 and some new ones.

there are some important fundamental changes (from 1.2.x to 2.0) I am still trying to wrap my head around. I would suggest to head over the mailing list for detailed questions if docs are unclear.

now to address your specifics.

> rewrite the templates

yes, you will need to do that. though, there are plans to support compatibility. no idea when it will be done though.

> additional steps would I need to perform to be up to date?

1. firstly, the project structure/setup/tools are different.
2. secondly, serving requests is different. For isntance in play2, you return `RESULT` object. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaActions) to get an idea.
3. thirdly, alot of modules are not available for 2.0. So if you rely on them, you will have to wait/write them yourself.

based on what I have seen, you would basically have to rewrite significant portions from 1.1 to 2.0.

You are better off upgrading to 1.2.4.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will upgrade to 1.2.x for the time being.

Comment: I tried to convert a project I am working on to 2.0, but decided against it when I realized that in 2.0, the form tag does not generate XSRF token. This was the proverbial straw. I relied on a bunch of modules which probably be ported to 2.0 in due time.