# How can I migrate play framework 1.2.4 to play 2.1?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

I am working on Play framework version 1.2.4. I want to migrate it to 2.1. Please let me know how can I do that.

The project is set on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. and we've managed to run our project's services as micro-services. each service can execute individually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960045/what-are-the-steps-for-migrating-from-play-1-1-to-2-0

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheRoussy Will go through the URL.